# How to use map state change event (zooment, moveend) with an html created by folium

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, folium

I render a map from an html file created by folium by using a python script. As the features of folium are quite restrictive, I have to write javascript code in the python script that will change the folium-based html file to add specific things to my map.

Til now it has worked just by string recognition and overwriting the html file. But now I need to use commands like map.on('zoomend', function() {...}). The problem is that folium uses its own generated map id, e.g. var map_4096f0e4e1cf5363f029e391a7951150 = L.map("map_4096f0e4e1cf5363f029e391a7951150",{...}). So I tried the get_name() function provided by folium, and I managed to have a string of the map id created by folium in its html file. But now I am stuck because it is a string version of the map id, so if I try in my python script {map_id}.on('zoomend',function(){...}), it won't recognized it as the map_id defined within the html file. I can't just manually change the html file as each time I reload the map page, the map id changes. So I need a dynamic way of retrieving this map id so that I can use it in my python code for "map state change event" -based coding. Or is there a totally other way of doing? (I hope I was clear with my question, the web development world is really new to me).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.